# Set approveForAll from a contract on another contract

Tags: solidity, nft, erc721

I have two smart contracts (A, B), which are extended from `ERC721`. Is it possible to create a function in `B` to call `setApprovalForAll` on `A` from a user `Z`?

this is in contract `B`: `testApprove(A)` as user `Z`

```
    function testApprove(address _contract) public payable {
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("setApprovalForAll(address,bool)", address(this), true);
        (bool success,) = address(_contract).delegatecall(payload);
        require(success);
        bool result = ERC721(_contract).isApprovedForAll(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(result, "Approve not set!");
    }
```

`success` is `true,` and there was no error because it ran OK. But when I check if contract `B` is approved, it's not!

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("setApprovalForAll(address,bool)", address(this), true);
(bool success,) = address(_contract).delegatecall(payload);
```

If this was invoked with regular `.call`, it would give approval from your contract (caller of the `setApprovalForAll()` function) to your contract (first param).

Since it's invoked with `.delegatecall`, the storage change is not performed on the target contract - but on your contract (the delegate caller). So all this snippet does, it sets a storage value of your contract in the same storage slot that the target would set the approval.

As per [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721), `setApprovalForAll()` sets the approval from `msg.sender`. So the only way to receive the approval from the user is to have them send the transaction directly to the token contract - not through any other contract in between.

Comment: So the short answer is that I cannot do this inside the contract because I cannot use `.call` that will make `msgSender()` and `operator` the same and it will throw an error.

Comment: @ZartoshtSepideman correct